# Can't create SQL Server 2012 database from Visual studio 2010 (SSDT) on my local PC

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am a new SQL Server programmer and this is my first question on stackoverflow. 
Anticipating your help...

I have these installed in my PC: Windows 7 ultimate SP1 + SQL Server 2012 Enterprise + Visual Studio 2010 (SSDT which came with my SQL Server 2012). What I want to do is create a database from SSDT.

In server explorer, I right clicked the data connection -> create new SQL Server database. After I input my server name and choose "Use Windows authentication" (which is the case with my SQL Server 2012), I got this warning:

> This server version is not supported. Only servers up to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 are supported.

What shall I do? Shall I upgrade to Visual studio 2013 or I have other options?

Much appreciated if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio isn't really the issue here. And you didn't say why you installed VS 2010 (are you actually developing apps with it?). If you're not actually developing in VS, I would remove it and just install the latest SSDT. This will install a VS shell, containing enough functionality to fully run SSDT. Then you should be able to create SQL Server 2012 databases, which I assume is what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't develop apps. This VS 2010, SSDT is just another name of it, was installed together with my SQL Server 2012 installation. I would like to go with what you are suggesting and  I found that the latest SSDT only comes with Visual Studio 2013:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027
Am I correct?

Comment: Not exactly correct. You don't need to install VS 2013 to get SSDT. You can install SSDT without VS 2013. If you do, SSDT will install a VS 2013 shell (not the entire app).

Comment: Thanks Randy. 
More specificly, I can't find the menu to connect to my local SQL Server instance from my SSDT. But I can connect to the databases on it. I think the issue is with my SSDT version. Can you please provide a link from which I can download a newer version of SSDT? I have a Microsoft web platform installer but can't find the newer SSDT in it.

Comment: Thanks Randy. I found that I have to download the whole VS 2013. I am gonna do that.